# Clojure: Is there a placeholder form/function?

Tags: java, clojure, lisp

I was using condp form and noticed in its doc:

> If no default expression is provided and no clause matches, an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.

I do not need to deal with non-match also don't want to surround condp with try form. I am thinking of putting a placeholder there. What is the fastest and easiest Clojure placeholder form?

Edit:

Thanks for everyone's opinions, very helpful! The use case of this behaviour is that in a user triggered, forced data recovery task, my application needs to dynamically parse Clojure code to recover data from log file. Corrupted data (the non-matches) shall be ignored and the same form if written in cond will take more key strokes than condp.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I see aib's point... this is a very loaded question.  Downvote pending clarification and addressing aib's concerns.  This could be very misleading.

Comment: Just to be clear - if side effects are in play, while that may be "bad form" - it's not as bad as giving an answer that someone (else) might take out of context.  It simply needs to be acknowledged to give full understanding of what's being addressed here.

Comment: Thanks Richard. The use case is to parse dynamic code in Clojure in a forced data recovery task and ignoring corrupted/incorrect data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

```
(condp = option
  :foo 1
  :bar 2
  3)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to deal with non-match (i.e. you can guarantee that there will always be a match) then you don't need to put anything there as a placeholder.

If your assumption that there will always be a match turns out to be wrong then you will get an IllegalArgumentException - but that is a *good thing* as it will immediately tell you that you have a logic error in your code. It's the good old [fail-fast principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) in action

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Use `nil`.

But the reason you don't need a default value is that you're sure at least one of the predicates will hold, right? It's not that you're relying on side effects, right?

Comment: I kinda liked your edited... it really focused hard on the salient points: a) strong suggestion that the tests cover *all* cases, b) use nil - though if you cover all cases this isn't necessary, and c) do NOT use side effects.

Comment: Okay, rolled back *again*. I guess I'm not fully awake yet :).

Comment: Thank you. The use case is to parse dynamic code in Clojure in a data recovery task and ignore corrupted/incorrect data.